# Typescript not assignable error after lodash property extend

Tags: typescript, lodash

I have defined a object and wish to extend the object with the optional parameter allowed. I am using lodash to iterate over the array and determine whether I wish to allow or not allow. When I try to make the assignment of myArray to temp I receive an error even though my object fits the correct format to be assignable.

> Type '({} & MyObject & { allowed: boolean; })[]' is not
>   assignable to type '[MyObject]'.   Property '0' is missing in type
>   '({} & MyObject & { allowed: boolean; })[]'.

```
export class MyObject {
  constructor(
  public id: number,
  public shortName: string,
  public name: string,
  public allowed?: boolean
  ){}
}

var temp = _.map(this.myArray, function(element) {
  if (_.includes(event, element.id))
    return _.extend({}, element, {allowed: false});
  else
    return _.extend({}, element, {allowed: true});
});
this.myArray = temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Because type of `MyObject[]` and `[MyObject]` is different, `_.map<T>(arr:T[])` returns `T[]` rather than `[T]`.

You should specify the type of `myArray` explicitly as follow:

```
this.myArray: MyObject[] = [new MyObject(0, '', '')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Been running into this issue with WebStorm, something like this fixes it, though not very pretty.

```
   export class MyObject {
      constructor(
      public id: number,
      public shortName: string,
      public name: string,
      public allowed?: boolean
      ){}
    }

    var temp = _.map(this.myArray, function(element) {
      var object: MyObject = _.extend({}, element, <{allowed: boolean}>{allowed: _.includes(event, element.id)});
      return object; 
    });

    this.myArray = temp
```